# React SetState Doesn't cause rerender, and forceupdate() doesn't work either

Tags: reactjs

I'm changing the states on this code several times, but no matter what I do, the component never reloads. Even trying to force the issue by calling this.forceUpdate() doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong? I'm updating code with this.setState, and the states are successfully being changed. But I still don't know why not a single place the this.setState() method is called, the component never gets re-rendered. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginError from './loginerror.component'


class LoginBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log("rendering");
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            login_username: "" ,
            login_password: "",
            login_status: "Hello"
        };
    }

    onChangeUsername(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            login_username: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangePassword(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            login_password: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let userN = this.state.login_username;
        let passW = this.state.login_password;
        let fetchURL = "http://weightwatchbackend-env.eba-jkqtmzzk.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?username=" + userN + "&password=" + passW;


        fetch(fetchURL)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((text) => {
                this.setState({
                    login_status: text
                })
                this.forceUpdate();
            })
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div id = "LoginBoxOuter">
                <div id = "Loginbox">
                    <div id = "LoginTop"><h2>Login</h2></div>

                    <div id = "LoginBottom">
                        <div id = "LoginForms">
                            <plaintext>username:</plaintext><input type = "text" onChange = {this.onChangeUsername}></input><br></br>
                            <plaintext>Password:</plaintext><input type = "text" onChange = {this.onChangePassword}></input><br></br>
                            <LoginError type = {this.state.login_status}/>
                        </div>

                        <div className = "LoginButtonOuter">
                            <div className = "LoginButtonInner">
                                <button onClick = {this.onSubmit}>Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className = "LoginButtonOuter">
                            <div className = "LoginButtonInner">
                                <button>Sign up</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default LoginBox;
```

Comment: `console.log("rendering");` - constructor is called once, move this to `render()` method before `return` statement

Comment: please provide a codesandbox example like this : https://codesandbox.io/s/q63788920-cf873?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark .. it may have the thing you want...

Comment: And if you want to use readymade library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mua-login

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value of your state to your input field.

```
<input type ="text" onChange={this.onChangeUsername} value={this.state.login_username} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below:

```
<plaintext>username:</plaintext><input type="text" name="login_username" value={this.state.login_username} onChange {this.onChangeUsername}></input><br></br>
<plaintext>Password:</plaintext><input type="text" name="login_password" value={this.state.login_password} onChange={this.onChangePassword}></input><br></br>
```